# Missing properties in thermodynamic property table

Tags: thermodynamics

In Fundamentals of Thermodynamics by Borgnakke and Sonntag, why there are missing properties (dashes) in the thermodynamic property tables?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about a physical concept.

Comment: @TobiasFünke How can you be sure that this question is not about a physical concept?

Comment: Well, sure it is somehow about physics. But for me the question seems off-topic, because you simply ask "why are there no values in **this** table?". Have you checked other data? What source does the author cite? Have you checked that? etc....

Comment: I disagree with the close votes. As an answer explains, the omitted values are unphysical, and *no* similar table would include them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the table notes in the top row, at 20 MPa water boils at ≈366°C.  So there's no row for 350°C because water is not a gas at that temperature and pressure.